# Python 2.7 - Dropbox API V2. Download whole folder

Tags: python-2.7, dropbox

I have an App Folder in my dropbox, and in that folder, let's say there is a folder called 'database'. 
How would I go about downloading the whole folder's contents and putting it into a folder, *or* reading each files contents one-by-one?
(The latter is preferable as I assume that would use the least amount of processing power)

Thank you!

To sum up: I need to get a whole folder's file contents, and save them locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer, though it doesn't use the Dropbox API, it uses URLLIB.

```
URL = "dropbox folder link"
globalData = urllib.urlretrieve(URL, "file-destination")
```

Simple :)